# after divide images to div..cant change specific div(part of img) color

Tags: html, css

I divided an images to lot of `<divs>`, in the main css class `#background-container` i used `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);` filter, now i just don't understand how to change one specific `<div>` to his original color(remove the flittering effect),i tried alot and i'm not asking you to do my job... i need direction :\

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/131/

HTML

```
<div id="background-container">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blocks {
    display:table-row;
}

.block {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100px;
    border:15px solid #FFF;
}

#background-container { 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background: url(http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

thank you guys !

Comment: apply a specific class to each block and assign the new special css to it that you want it to have.

Comment: `#background-container` is not a css class, it's a set of rules applied to a particular element using an `id` selector. css classes are marked with `.` which can be applied to multiple elements

Comment: ya i know i didnt see this before.but still i cant get it work @VikingBlooded , any suggestions? :\

Comment: Do you have full control over the HTML that is generated?

Comment: @VikingBlooded i think i do.. not sure if i get it correct lol

Comment: Ok, so first of all, the container div class blocks, needs to be a different class than the divs it contains. Try that, then style that class of divs.

Comment: @VikingBlooded dam it i cant understand :( do you have skype? im promise i will not ask you 1 more question after this one.. im building a website for the 3 israeli boys who kidnapped.. and i need to do this asap :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because the filter effect is being applied to the parent container rather than each child block. Unlike real-life filters, you can't apply CSS filters to an element and have it affect the content that is visible underneath it.

What you would have to do is apply the background to each block and then dynamically position it to line up, applying and toggling the filter for each (or swapping out that block's background for pre-grayscaled version). Not that hard if your container is a fixed size but a lot of JavaScript work if it's meant to be fluid like your example.